# Consecutive fade in fade out animations

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to implement this animation where a `UIButton` fades out when a user saves a file.  While the button fades out, a `UIImageView` of a check mark image fades in place of the button.  Once the imageview has fully faded in, then it fades out and the button fades back in.

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.60, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.recButton.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: {
            (value: Bool) in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.60, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
                self.checkView.alpha = 1.0
                }, completion: {
                    (value: Bool) in
                    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.60, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
                        self.checkView.alpha = 0.0
                        }, completion: {
                            (value: Bool) in
                            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.60, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
                                self.recButton.alpha = 1.0
                                self.recButton.enabled = true
                                }, completion: nil)
                    })
            })
    })
```

While the method above does work, its not as smooth as I would like.  Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: You could use a keyframed animation [like shown here](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/04/01/stop-nesting-animation-blocks/)

Comment: @Palle this looks like the cleaner approach, but I don't see how you can make a nice fade in/out animation work with the `UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions` options.

Answer (score 3):

You need four keyframes for the animation you want: button fade out, image fade in, image fade out, button fade in.

```
let button: UIButton
let checkmarkImage: UIImageView

button.alpha = 1.0
checkmarkImage = 0.0

UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(2.4, delay: 0, options: .CalculationModeLinear, animations: {
  UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.0, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: { 
    button.alpha = 0.0
  })
  UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.25, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
    checkmarkImage.alpha = 1.0
  })
  UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.5, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
    checkmarkImage.alpha = 0.0
  })
  UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.75, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
    button.alpha = 1.0
  })
}, completion: nil)
```

This question raised my curiosity - this keyframe thing is pretty cool.